# Connect NodeMCU with USB camera

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, usb, camera

I am trying to connect a USB camera to my NodeMCU v0.9.

- VCC  Red             +5V
- D-       White           Data
- D+       Green           Data
- GND  Black           Ground

I dismantled the USB cable and connected the VCC cable to 5 V and the black ground cable to GND.

Now I have a DATA + and DATA - cable from the USB, which I connected to the D5/D6 GPIOs of the NodeMCU. I can now read the digital signal of the camera.

But I am not quite sure how to process the data cable's signal. I am not familiar with the USB data + / - cable concept.

Any ideas on how I can process the video image ?

Comment: You can't. USB is complex, and the video data over it even more complex.

Comment: https://www.cnx-software.com/2016/08/08/esp8266-gets-usb-support-thanks-to-espusb-software-stack/

Comment: A) that's device mode, not host mode. B) that's low speed which means keyboard and mouse only.

Comment: no, but you _can_ get a camera that connects by serial or SPI or i2c

Answer (score 3):

You can't. It's as simple as that. To do it you require:

1. An MCU or MPU with a USB Host or OTG module built in.
2. Drivers for that module to enumerate the device
3. Drivers for the specific device you are connecting
4. Software to deal with the data provided by the device.

The ESP8266 has none of those.

Sounds to me like you want a Raspberry Pi.